# ASP.NET user authentication fails in debug, but not in production

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net website that I am able to log into after it is published in production, but when I run the actual code in debug, I cannot log in using the same credentials.  When debugging the code, I see I am able to retrieve the user's profile from the database.

Perhaps I am missing some sort of Visual Studio configuration?

I am debugging the solution from a solution file that points to the file location of the project.  Maybe I am missing something in the solution file as well.

Comment: What error message do you see if any?

Comment: There is no error message.  The only message is a programmed notification that authentication failed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.  It looks like the way the application uses the URL parameters after logging in, the parameter must be in all upper case.  I initially had it entered in mixed case.  This is why it was failing the authentication.